Effect-Size Analysis: Cohen's D, Pearson's r, or something else?
I am trying to do an effect-size analysis on dam release's effects on downstream temperature. I have a large dataset of data loggers taking temperature readings at various sites downstream from the dam. I am trying to compare these downstream sites versus a temperature gauge placed at the foot on the dam (serving as my independent variable). After asking a few questions, it seemed like an effect-size analysis is what I am looking for. Doing some research, I see lots of mention of Cohen's d and Pearson's r.
I have controlled for travel time downstream by shifting the data to fit the water's travel time. I have also have done a central 24 hour average of the data to try and get rid of the diurnal fluctuations in water temperature to hopefully not bias the correlation (that is why the 24hrAVG columns have so many NA's at the start of the dataset). Here is my data set.
> dput(head(SaltData_))
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1709942400, 1709943300, 1709944200, 
1709945100, 1709946000, 1709946900), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), S1 = c(12.824443359375, 12.824443359375, 12.824443359375, 
12.824443359375, 12.824443359375, 12.78154296875), S2 = c(12.86734375, 
12.86734375, 12.86734375, 12.910244140625, 12.86734375, 12.824443359375
), S3 = c(12.223837890625, 12.223837890625, 12.26673828125, 12.26673828125, 
12.223837890625, 12.26673828125), S4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 7.8908984375, 
7.847998046875), S5 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), S6 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), S7 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), S8 = c(12.309638671875, 12.309638671875, 
12.26673828125, 12.3525390625, 12.3525390625, 12.309638671875
), S9 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
), S10 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_), S11 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_), GaugeTemp = c(8.2, 8.2, 8.2, 8.2, 8.2, 8.2), GaugeHeight = c(70.83, 
70.84, 70.84, 70.85, 70.83, 70.83), Column1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), `24hrAVG S1` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `24hrAVG S4` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `24hrAVG S5` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `24hr AVG S6` = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `24hrAVG S7` = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `24hrAVG S8` = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `24hrAVG S9` = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `24hrAVG S10` = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `24hrAVG S11` = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `24hrAVG GaugeTemp` = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `24hrAVG GaugeHeight` = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

After doing some Pearson's r correlation tests, it seems like this test is not finding the results I would expect. The correlation / effect of dam release initially goes down as you head downstream (i.e. S4 and GaugeTemp r is 0.92, S5 and GaugeTemp r is 0.843, S6 and GaugeTemp r is 0.8276), but jumps back up as soon as site S7 (0.828) and continues that way. What I should be seeing is a steady decrease in correlation / effect size as you head downstream because more and more tributaries wash out the dam releases effect.
So what I am wondering is if Cohen's d would solve my problem, or if I am even in the right place thinking about effect-size using Pearson's r or Cohen's d. I have been struggling with this question for a long time, so any help would be MUCH appreciated. I can also provide more data / graphs if needed, just let me know in the comments and I'd be happy to share.

I am not a hydrodynamics expert, but I would naively expect that the effect of increased flow from a dam would be more notable at sites just above flow restrictions than at sites where there is no restriction, and also would expect that the slopes of the site would also be relevant. Therefore I am wondering if your intuition that there should be a constant gradient of correlation coefficients might be faulty.

I hadn’t even thought about that. I am just a summer intern, so I am by far and away not an expert, but rather quite the opposite of it. This I think is a great way to think about it and I’ll make sure to add it into my study. Still doesn’t answer the problem of testing the data though. How would I go about comparing them? I do now plan on using multiple variables (site flow, gauge height from the dam site, air temperature), but what is a good test / way of comparing all of these to see what is the ‘major’ impact on the downstream site’s temperatures. That is the crux of what I am need.

I have a verryyy basic understanding of stats so I have been trying to get a lot of help from stackexchange. It helps me a lot to know what people who know what they are talking about think about my questions. Thanks.
